# React Material-UI Autocomplete customize `no options` text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking at this example of Autocomplete provided by MaterialUI

https://codesandbox.io/s/81qc1

I was wondering how I can display a "No options found" message if no results are found.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use props **noOptionsText** for Material-UI Autocomplete

> Text to display when there are no options.
> For localization purposes, you can use the provided translations.

- Ref: [Document of Autocomplete API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

```
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

<Autocomplete
  noOptionsText={'Your Customized No Options Text'}
  ...
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any option if I don't want to show the noOption popper? If I set it to null or false it still shows blank popper

Comment: @hardiksa Maybe you could add a js conditional style to the dropdown area via its className (using MUI style nesting selector).

Comment: @keikai could you elaborate of how that would work? Maybe even show an example?

Answer (score 30):

For those who don't want "No options" to show up at all,

```
<Autocomplete freeSolo />
```

Comment: Mister, you deserve a bag of cookies!

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, so THANKS!!!!!!!!! Also instead of true, I added a condition to not show this before 6 characters to fetch the option list. Basically show it after I really know there are no options.

Comment: Omg, i got what i needed, thanks a million!!!

Comment: You don't need to set true. `freeSolo` is enough

Comment: Chocolate chip cookies

Comment: No longer supported: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-goodall-f4vn9w?file=/src/Demo.tsx

This works tho: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-goodall-f4vn9w?file=/src/Demo.tsx

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of a conditional on `freeSolo` and the `noOptionsText` field... like so:

```
<Autocomplete
    freeSolo={inputValue?.length ? false : true}
    loading={isMatchingUsersLoading}
    loadingText={"Searching..."}
    options={matchingUsers}
    noOptionsText={"No matches..."}
    .... 
/>
```

This will keep the 'empty box' from showing up AND still give you the `noOptionsText` and the `loading` text at appropriate times.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation looking for `noOptionsText` prop: https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

```
const theme = createTheme(
  {
    components: {
      MuiAutocomplete: {
        defaultProps: {
          noOptionsText: 'any text you want',
        },
      },
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Reviewed it in low quality answers queue. While it's code-only, in my opinion it's also self explanatory

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to check this [link](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) for fast and easy Autocomplete implementation. But if you want to build your own Autocomplete component using useAutocomplete check [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L465)